# PIC32 UART: U1RXREG Register Never Contains Any Values Other Than 0

Tags: c, uart, pic32

I've attached an image showing my oscilloscope readout which is from the code below. Context: I have a Pi and a PIC which need to communicate through UART connection. I've implemented my own flow control which can be seen in the image attached [RTS = Yellow Trace, CTS = Blue Trace, Rx = Green Trace]. The code runs through and is caught in the final switch case statement which turns on an LED. But when i debug the code, no values (well the only value which is read is zero) are read in. At first i thought that i'd configured my PIC clock wrong (which is used to derive the baud rate), but i don't think this is the case. Second i through the FIFO buffer was full of zeros only and considering that i'm sending only four packets of information to the PIC, and my FIFO is 4 registers deep that this was the reason why non of the information was appearing. So i executed a code which removes the dummy bytes but this did not work.

All that is received: 
0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0> etc

I got the right settings selected: baud rate: 9600 data bits: 8 parity: none stop bits: 1

If anyone is willing to spend some time looking at my code, can you see any obvious errors?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQoAL.jpg

Minimum Reproducible Example

```
#  include <xc.h>
#  include <math.h>
#  include <stdio.h>
#  include <stdio.h>

//Configuration Bits 
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCPLL    // Internal Fast RC Oscillator (8MHz)
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2  // Divide FRC before PLL (Now 4MHz)
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_20  // PLL Multiply (Now 80MHz)
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_2  // Divide After PLL (Now 40MHz)
#pragma config FPBDIV = DIV_1    // Pheripheral Bus Clock (At 40KHz)

#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF      // Watchdog Timer Disabled 
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx2 // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select 
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF      // Disable JTAG 
#pragma config FSOSCEN = OFF     // Disable Secondary Oscillator 

//*****************************UART Functions*********************************** 

void UART_Config (void)                 // Baude Rate of 9600, 8-Bit Data , 1 Stop Bit                                           
{   
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;           
    U1BRG = 259;                         //U1BRG = (40M/ (16 * 9.6k))) - 1
    U1MODEbits.SIDL = 0;                 // Continue operation in SLEEP mode
    U1MODEbits.IREN = 0;                 // IrDA is disabled
    U1MODEbits.RTSMD = 0;                // U1RTS pin is in Flow Control mode   
    U1MODEbits.UEN = 0b00;               // U1TX, U1RX are enabled
    U1MODEbits.WAKE = 1;                 // Wake-up enabled
    U1MODEbits.LPBACK = 0;               // Loopback mode is disabled
    U1MODEbits.RXINV = 0;                // U1RX IDLE state is '1'
    U1MODEbits.PDSEL = 0b00;             // 8-bit data, no parity
    U1MODEbits.STSEL = 0;                // 1 stop bit
    U1STAbits.UTXINV = 0;                // U1TX IDLE state is '1'
    U1MODEbits.ON = 1;                   // UART1 is enabled
    U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;                 // UART1 receiver is enabled
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;                 // UART1 transmitter is enabled
}

void Send_UART_Data(unsigned int c)     // PIC Sending Data for Pi to Read 
{
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;                // Make sure transmitter is enabled
    // while(CTS)                       // Optional CTS (Clear to Send) use
    while(U1STAbits.UTXBF);             // Wait while buffer is full
    U1TXREG = c;                        // Transmit character
}

int Read_UART_Data (void)               // PIC Reading Sent Data from Pi 
{
    int c;

    while(!U1STAbits.URXDA)             // Wait for information to be received

    c = (int)U1RXREG;                    // Convert Character to Value
    return c; 
}

ADC_To_UART (unsigned int ADC)
{
    unsigned int temp_A = 0x00;
    unsigned int temp_B = 0x00;
                          // Splitting a 10 Bit Word Into 2 Bytes [aa aaaa aabb]
                          // Start Bit = 1 , Stop Bit = 0 
                          // UART Transmission Pattern [1 aaaa aaaa 0 0000 00 bb]
    temp_A = ADC >> 2;    // MSB(8 Bits) ~ ADC[9:2] [aaaa aaaa]   
    temp_B = ADC & 0x003; // LSB(2 Bits) ~ ADC[1:0] [0000 00bb]

    Send_UART_Data(temp_A);
    Send_UART_Data(temp_B);
}
[enter image description here][1]
//*********************Enumerated Variable Declaration**************************
//Program Flow Control
enum Comm_State {Phase1A, Phase1B, Phase1C, Phase1D, Phase1E, Phase2A, Phase2B, Phase2C, Phase2D, Phase2E, Phase2F, Phase2G};

//******************************************************************************
//********************************MAIN******************************************

int main( )
{   
    //***************************Configuration**********************************
    // I/O Definitions 
    #define UART_TRIS_RX       TRISBbits.TRISB13 // UART RX - Reciever Pin (PPS) 
    #define UART_TRIS_TX       TRISBbits.TRISB15 // UART TX - Transmission Pin (PPS) 
    #define UART_TRIS_CTS_PIC  TRISAbits.TRISA4  // UART CTS_1 - Clear to Send - Output [CTS PIC]
    #define UART_TRIS_RTS_PIC  TRISBbits.TRISB4  // UART RTS_1 - Ready to Send - Output [RTS PIC]
    #define UART_TRIS_CTS_PI   TRISAbits.TRISA3  // UART CTS_2 - Clear to Send - Input  [CTS PI]
    #define UART_TRIS_RTS_PI   TRISAbits.TRISA2  // UART_RTS_2 - Ready to Send - Input  [RTS PI]

    #define SPI_TRIS_SCK       TRISBbits.TRISB14  // SPI SCK - Serial Clock Pin      (PPS?)
    #define SPI_TRIS_SDO       TRISBbits.TRISB6   // SPI SDO - Serial Data Out Pin   (PPS?)
    #define SPI_TRIS_CS_1      TRISBbits.TRISB8   // SPI CS1 - DAC 2 Chip Select Pin (PPS?)
    #define SPI_TRIS_CS_2      TRISBbits.TRISB7   // SPI CS2 - DAC 1 Chip Select Pin (PPS?)

    #define AN4_TRIS           TRISBbits.TRISB2   // Analogue Read 3
    #define AN3_TRIS           TRISBbits.TRISB1   // Analogue Read 2
    #define AN2_TRIS           TRISBbits.TRISB0   // Analogue Read 1
    #define V_REF_TRIS_Plus    TRISAbits.TRISA0   // Analogue V_REF(+) (Forms VRange)
    #define V_REF_TRIS_Minus   TRISAbits.TRISA1   // Analogue V_REF(-) (Forms VRange)

    #define Reg_Enable_TRIS_D  TRISBbits.TRISB9   // Regulator Digital Control (Output) 
    #define Reg_Enable_TRIS_M  TRISBbits.TRISB12  // Regulator Button (Input)

    // Port Input/Output Configuration [TRISB]

    TRISB = 0x1004;           // All of PortB set as Outputs Except for RB12 (Reg Enable) and RB2 (Input -> Analogue Input (Voltage)) (Port B) = (0000 ... 0100)
    TRISA = 0x0003;           // Set up A0 [Pin 2] and A1 [Pin 3] as V_REF(+) and V_REF(-) Respectively (Port B) = (0000 ... 0011) 

    UART_TRIS_RX  = 1;        // UART Receiver ~ Input  
    UART_TRIS_TX  = 0;        // UART Transmission ~ Output 
    UART_TRIS_CTS_PIC = 0;    // UART "CTS_PIC" ~ Output
    UART_TRIS_RTS_PIC = 0;    // UART "RTS_PIC" ~ Output
    UART_TRIS_CTS_PI = 1;     // UART "CTS_PI" ~ Input
    UART_TRIS_RTS_PI = 1;     // UART "RTS_PI" ~ Input 

    SPI_TRIS_SCK  = 0;        // SPI Clock ~ Output
    SPI_TRIS_SDO  = 0;        // SPI Data Output ~ Output 
    SPI_TRIS_CS_1 = 0;        // SPI Chip Select 1 ~ Output 
    SPI_TRIS_CS_2 = 0;        // SPI Chip Select 2 ~ Output 

    AN4_TRIS = 1;             // Analogue Read In ~ Input       
    AN3_TRIS = 1;             // Analogue Read In ~ Input
    AN2_TRIS = 1;             // Analogue Read In ~ Input
    V_REF_TRIS_Plus = 1;      // V_Ref(+) ~ Input  
    V_REF_TRIS_Minus = 1;     // V_Ref(-) Differential Measurements ~ Input

    Reg_Enable_TRIS_D = 0;    // Regulator Digital Control (Output) 
    Reg_Enable_TRIS_M = 1;    // Regulator Switch Control (Input)

    // Peripheral Pin Select Configurations
    U1RXR  = 0x0011;          // UART PPS Mapping 
    RPB15R = 0x0001;          // UART PPS Mapping 

    // Analogue Pin Configurations  
    ANSELB = 0x0028;           // RB0 RB1 RB2 = AN2 AN3 AN4 [0001 1100]  
    ANSELA = 0x0000;           // Set all Analogue Inputs of Port A Off

    //**************Sub-System Configurations*********************************//

    // UART Control Configure 
    UART_Config();                              //UART Control Configure      
    #define PIC_CTS  LATAbits.LATA4             // Output Set  Definition [1]
    #define PIC_RTS  LATBbits.LATB4             // Output Set  Definition [2]
    #define PI_CTS   PORTAbits.RA3              // Input  Read Definition [2]
    #define PI_RTS   PORTAbits.RA2              // Input  Read Definition [1]

    // Analogue Control Configure  
    ADC_Config();                               // Configure ADC 
    AD1CON1SET = 0x8000;                        // Enable ADC

    //***************Variable Declarations************************************//

    enum Comm_State Communication_State = Phase1A;        //Controller Variable 

    unsigned int temp1 = 0;
    unsigned int Comms_Flag_1 = 0;
    unsigned int ConFlag = 1; 
    unsigned int i = 1; 

    unsigned int UART_ADC_CV_1 = 0;
    unsigned int UART_ADC_CV_2 = 0;
    unsigned int ADC_CV = 0;
    unsigned int UART_ADC_CC_1 = 0;
    unsigned int UART_ADC_CC_2 = 0;
    unsigned int ADC_CC = 0;

    unsigned int DAC_CV = 0;

    float I_CC = 0; 
    float V_CV = 0;

    //***************Program Flow - Switch State Controlled*******************//

    while(1)
    {
        switch (Communication_State)
        {
            case Phase1A:  // Check For Pi Ready to Send CV ADC Value

                //PIC_CTS = 0; 
                //Pic_Refresh();
                PIC_RTS = 0; 
                PIC_CTS = 1;

                if (PI_RTS == 1)
                {
                    PIC_CTS = 0;
                    Communication_State = Phase1B;
                }

                break;

            case Phase1B:  // Receive CV ~ 12 Bit ADC Value [Two Data Packets with 0.01 Second Delay]

                ConFlag = 1; 
                i = 1; 

                while (ConFlag == 1)
                {
                    if (PI_RTS == 1 && i == 1)
                    {
                        UART_ADC_CV_1 = Read_UART_Data();   //Data Packet 1 Returned - MSB(Bit 15) to Bit 8
                        i++;
                    }

                    else if (PI_RTS == 1 && i == 2)
                    {
                        UART_ADC_CV_2 = Read_UART_Data();   //Data Packet 2 Returned - Bit (7)) to LSB(Bit 0)
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        ConFlag = 0;
                    }
                }

                Communication_State = Phase1C;
                break;

            case Phase1C:  // Check for CC Value

                delay();        //Ensure that Pi_RTS has gone low after sending last Transmission (Prevents Code from Running Away)
                PIC_CTS = 1;

                if (PI_RTS == 1)
                {
                    PIC_CTS = 0; 
                    Communication_State = Phase1D;
                }

                break;

            case Phase1D:   // Receive CC Value [Two Data Packets with 0.01 Second Delay]

                ConFlag = 1; 
                i = 1; 

                while (ConFlag == 1)
                {
                    if (PI_RTS == 1 && i == 1)
                    {
                        UART_ADC_CC_1 = Read_UART_Data();   //Data Packet 1 Returned - MSB(Bit 15) to Bit 8
                        i++;
                    }

                    else if (PI_RTS == 1 && i == 2)
                    {
                        UART_ADC_CC_2 = Read_UART_Data();   //Data Packet 2 Returned - Bit (7)) to LSB(Bit 0)
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        ConFlag = 0;
                    }
                }

                Communication_State = Phase1E;
                break;

            case Phase1E:  // Calculations 

                // CV Calculations 
                temp1 = UART_ADC_CV_1 << 8;
                ADC_CV = temp1 + UART_ADC_CV_2;
                V_CV = ADC_CV * (4.096/4096);
                DAC_CV = ADC_CV | 4096;
                Comms_Flag_1 = SPI_Transfer(DAC_CV ,1);    // Data Transmitted to DAC 1, Upon Transmission LED Turns Green (No Acknowledgement)

                // CC Calculations 
                temp1 = UART_ADC_CC_1 << 8;
                ADC_CC = temp1 + UART_ADC_CC_2;
                I_CC = ADC_CC * (4.096/4096);

                Communication_State = Phase2A;

                break;

            case Phase2A:

                while(1)
                {
                    LATBbits.LATB5 = 1;
                }

                break;

        }

    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Read_UART_Data`, you have:

```
while(!U1STAbits.URXDA)
c = (int)U1RXREG;
```

---

I think you're missing a semicolon because this is actually:

```
while (!U1STAbits.URXDA)
    c = (int) U1RXREG;
```

This means that `c` is set *only* when the UART receiver is *not* ready.

---

What I think you meant is:

```
while (!U1STAbits.URXDA);
c = (int) U1RXREG;
```

Comment: Fixing this line of code lead to more sensical readings. The program now freezes as the U1STAbits.URXDA bit is never set. Even though packets of information are being sent from the Pi which is confusing as i believed that pulling the Rx line low would be the first step to setting the URXDA bit.